# What does it mean when people say CPython is written in C?

Tags: python, cpython

From what I know, CPython programs are compiled into intermediate bytecode, which is executed by the virtual machine. Then how does one identify without knowing beforehand that CPython is written in C. Isn't there some common DNA for both which can be matched to identify this?

Comment: I think this is a genuine, if confused, question. Downvote if you want, but I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: Consider the fact that a book about how to read (i.e. "interpret") English texts can be written in a different language than English - say, French. In the same sense, the Python interpreter, which knows how to interpret texts in the Python language, was written another language: C. And just like you can have multiple books (written in different languages!) about how to read Englis, you can have programs which are able to interpret Python programs written in different languages. C, Pascal - and even Python itself.

Comment: "without knowing beforehand that python is written in C". You don't know that. But Python is open source, so you can download it, look at it, and see that it is written in C.

Comment: @Joe In my opinion, it is off topic because it shows that OP lacks the required minimal understanding of what he's asking - in this case, basics about programming languages and program execution, like the distinction between compiled and interpreted languages. I don't think any answer can reasonably clean up his confusion about this, an introductory book or programming course would probably required. So, it doesn't matter if the question is genuine or not, I think its scope doesn't fit this site...

Comment: I think there's a continuum of knowledge. I don't see a particular cut-off point. I like to try and help people wherever they are on that scale. Here's a confused question with a straightforward, correct, answer. I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python isn't written in C. Arguably, Python is written in an esoteric English dialect using BNF.

However, all the following statements are true:

1. *Python is a language, consisting of a language specification and a bunch of standard modules*
2. Python source code is compiled to a bytecode representation
3. this bytecode could in principle be executed directly by a suitably-designed processor but I'm not aware of one actually existing
4. in the absence of a processor that natively understands the bytecode, some *other* program must be used to translate the bytecode to something a hardware processor can understand
5. one real implementation of this runtime facility is CPython
6. CPython is itself *written in* C, but ...

   1. *C is a language, consisting of a language specification and a bunch of standard libraries*
   2. C source code is compiled to some bytecode format (typically something platform-specific)
   3. this platform specific format is typically the native instruction set of some processor (in which case it may be called "object code" or "machine code")
   4. this native bytecode doesn't retain any magical C-ness: it is just instructions. It doesn't make any difference to the processor which language the bytecode was compiled *from*
   5. so the CPython executable which translates your Python bytecode is a sequence of 
      instructions executing directly on your processor
   6. so you have: Python bytecode being interpreted by machine code being interpreted by the hardware processor
7. Jython is another implementation of the *same* Python runtime facility
8. Jython is written in Java, but ...

   1. *Java is a language, consisting of a spec, standard libraries etc. etc.*
   2. Java source code is compiled to a *different* bytecode
   3. Java bytecode is also executable either on suitable hardware, or by some runtime facility
   4. The Java runtime environment which provides this facility may also be written in C
   5. so you have: Python bytecode being interpreted by Java bytecode being interpreted by machine code being interpreted by the hardware processor

You can add more layers indefinitely: consider that your "hardware processor" may really be a software emulation, or that hardware processors may have a front-end that decodes their "native" instruction set into *another* internal bytecode.

All of these layers are defined by what they do (executing or interpreting instructions according to some specification), not how they implement it.

Oh, and I skipped over the compilation step. The C compiler is typically written in C (and getting any language to the stage where it can compile itself is traditionally significant), but it could just as well be written in Python or Java. Again, the compiler is defined by what it does (transforms some source language to some output such as a bytecode, according to the language spec), rather than how it is implemented.

Comment: thanks! helped a lot in understanding how higher level languages work :)

Answer (score 19):

The **interpreter** is written in C.

It compiles Python code into bytecode, and then an evaluation loop interprets that bytecode to run your code.

You identify what Python is written in by looking at it's source code. See the [source for the evaluation loop](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5bc3d8d22a93/Python/ceval.c) for example.

Note that the Python.org implementation is but one Python implementation. We call it CPython, because it is implemented in C. There are other implementations too, written in other languages. [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) is written in Java, [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) in C#, and then there is [PyPy](http://pypy.org/), which is written in a (subset of) Python, and runs many tasks [*faster* than CPython](http://speed.pypy.org).

Comment: @AnishShah: Don't confuse the language interpreter implementation with the language itself. If a C compiler is written in Fortran, does that mean you can use Fortran in your C code? Of course not!

Comment: @AnishShah No, because Python could also have been written in Java, assembler, Haskell, ... in any language.

Comment: @AnishShah: You can extend CPython with C extensions, see the [C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/). You can also access DLLs or shared object libraries with the [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), giving you access to many common C-implemented libraries.

Comment: could you post some link to an article where I could better understand language interpreter implementation?

Comment: @AnishShah: I may be misunderstanding what you are asking, but that sounds to me like **way** to broad a subject to answer with a link to an article.

Comment: @AnishShah there is the dragon book that is like a bible on the subject. But before reading it, you'll need to understand a lot of other concepts of programming, and should begin by mastering C and Python separately.

Comment: Your browser is written in C. Does a "c command" will run on it?

Comment: No, and it is precisely the reason why I asked the question and the answer to which was given by the user whose answer I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good understanding of my original doubt here:
http://amitsaha.github.io/site/notes/articles/c_python_compiler_interpreter.html